# How does "elemental" damage on weapons work with elemental skills?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have a weapon that adds Holy damage.  How does this work with my skills that say "Does X% of weapon damage as `INSERT ELEMENT` damage and things of that nature"?

Example:
My wand does 8-14 damage at 1.40 Attacks Per Second.  It has +1-2 Holy Damage for a total DPS rating of 15.4.  Ray of Frost deals 215% weapon damage as Cold damage.  How does this interact with the Holy damage?

What if the two elements are the same?

Comment: I *believe* that weapons with +elemental damage only apply to basic-attacks and attacks that do not do "X% as <Elemental Damage>".

Comment: @RavenDreamer I was thinking the "X% as <Elemental Damage>" might be calculated using the normal weapons damage (the 8-14 in my example) and then the weapon's elemental damamge simply added on top of that.

Comment: Nope. +Elemental Damage gets treated as +Damage when it comes to those kinds of skills. It all gets added together *before* being multiplied by the skill.

Comment: To the downvoter: I'd be happy to know how I can make this question better.

Comment: This question is now very similar to http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63599/what-weapon-effects-are-useless-for-wizards-or-witch-doctors

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Bonus elemental damage is *overridden* when using a skill that does damage of a particular specified element. You still receive the damage bonus, but it is no longer of the element specified by the item.

For example, if you have a weapon that does 20-40 damage, and a bonus of +4-8 Fire Damage, and use an ability that does 100% Weapon Damage *as Lightning Damage*, you would do 24-48 lightning damage with that ability.

If the ability *does not specify* a particular damage type, then it will deal damage based on your weapons inherent damage type.

Answer (score 2):

The +1-2 Holy damage only applies to basic attacks (When you're out of arcane power).

However, that extra damage IS still factored into how much damage your spells do:

On the character inventory screen, underneath the stats, will be a number next to "Damage".

This value factors in your character's primary attribute as well as any buffs or other modifiers currently affecting them.

This value is the baseline for spells that do %weapon damage.