# Demon Hunter skill Bola

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

I have a weapon that deals lightning damage and have the skill Bola equipped, does that skill eliminate the lightning damage? I don't see the lightning hitting the enemies like I used to after setting that skill.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does "elemental" damage on weapons work with elemental skills?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63646/how-does-elemental-damage-on-weapons-work-with-elemental-skills)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bola Shot does Fire damage by default (unruned), you can add the Thunder Ball rune for lightning damage when the bola explodes (from the description, it still does fire damage on the initial hit)