# Diablo 3 Wizard Specific Damage Type Bonus

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “elemental” damage on weapons work with elemental skills?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63646/how-does-elemental-damage-on-weapons-work-with-elemental-skills)

Afternoon all,

I'm starting to understand how damage is calculated, but have a quick question on item bonus damage.

Based on a semi-related post on damage calculation:

[How is skill damage calculated based on weapon damage?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/60281/how-is-skill-damage-calculated-based-on-weapon-damage)

It is stated that bonus damage on items is just treated as a flat damage increase.

My question is, if you are using say...Arcane Orb, does an item with + to Arcane damage affect Arcane Orb differently than say Poison damage?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Raven Dreamer posts in an answer to that question,

> +elemental damage is effectively "+damage" as far as the system is concerned

This means that there is no difference between +arcane damage and +poison damage as far as calculating the total damage than an ability will do.

In other words, if you are just interested in what total damage will be done, +arcane damage = +posion damage = +damage.

Comment: Very interesting, I questioned because he said effectively, it seemed like he was trying to state that there are exceptions to the rule.  Kind of weird Blizzard would design it in such a way that this is the case, why not only have flat +damage rather than adding the elemental damage as well.  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @dardo It seems like they wanted both weapon bonuses and skills to affect damage type, but didn't want to do a complicated multi-type damage system like WoW has developed, so they compromised. See the question linked as "possible duplicate" for more info.